# How can I create a easy Python webserver

Tags: webserver

I wanted to create my own web server following the instructions for this website "https://pythonbasics.org/webserver/".

I entered the code "python3 -m http.server" in my Python program but I only get the error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax".

Then I entered this link "http://127.0.0.1:8080/" in my browser but I only get the error "Access error: 404 - not found Document cannot be found: / ".

What did I do wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be 2 problems:

- `python3 -m http.server` is meant to be run from a command-line, not from your python code.

From python interpreter:

```
>>> python -m http.server
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python -m http.server
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

From command-line

```
$> python3 -m http.server
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...
```

This command runs a python interpreter and loads the HTTP server classes from the module http.
In order to spawn a http server from your code, have a look at the [http.server documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html).

- If you get a http 404 error on 127.0.0.1:8080 **after** having the `SyntaxError`, you probably already have something listening on the port 8080.
  In that case, you won't be able to bind your webserver on it as the port is already busy. (but you must choose another port)

Also, **please note** the http.server module is for testing purposes only ! (as noted on the module's page)